# fileUpload: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUplo

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

i click submit form , tomcat lance exception

ps: click submit for test, not upload document (pdf)

ps2: i have form (name, tel, tel2, email, matriculation) within form

primefaces 4.0
upload.jar 1.3
io.jar 2.4

```
 Out 17, 2013 8:13:08 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
Advertência: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decode(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:44)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decode(FileUploadRenderer.java:44)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:771)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1225)
   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:676)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2786)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2640)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:2810)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1082)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decodeAdvanced(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:60)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decode(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:37)
   ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:806)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:261)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:285)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2722)
   ... 35 more

Out 17, 2013 8:13:08 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
Grave: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2786)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2640)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:2810)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1082)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decodeAdvanced(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:60)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decode(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:37)
   at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decode(FileUploadRenderer.java:44)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.decode(UIInput.java:771)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1225)
   at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processDecodes(UIInput.java:676)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:806)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:261)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:285)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2722)
   ... 35 more
```

My code xhtml

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

   <h:body>   

         <ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">
         <ui:param name="bean" value="#{segundaChamadaProvaBean}" />
         <ui:define name="cabecalho">
            <ui:include src="/template/topo.xhtml" />
         </ui:define>

         <ui:define name="corpo">
         <h:form id = "formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<br/><br/>

               NOS TERMOS DO REGIMENTO INTERNO REQUER 2º CHAMADA DAS DISCIPLINAS
               ABAIXO, CONFORME <b>ORIGINAL DO ATESTADO MÉDICO ANEXO E REFERENTE À:</b>

               <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                  <p:outputLabel for="uploadFile" value = "Anexar:"/>
                  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}"
                     id="uploadFile"
                     mode="advanced"                                                                                                    
                     label="Procurar..."                           
                     uploadLabel="Carregar"
                    cancelLabel="Cancelar"                              
                    dragDropSupport="true"
                    fileLimit="1"
                    fileLimitMessage="Limite máximo de upload 1."
                    invalidSizeMessage="Tamanho máximo 20mb"
                    sizeLimit="20971520"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                    required="true" 
                    invalidFileMessage="Arquivo inválido somente é aceito pdf."
                    requiredMessage="Porfavor fazer upload de documento."
                    auto="true"
                    />  
               </h:panelGrid>
Concordo com os termos acima.
             <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id = "concordoTermos" value = "#{segundaChamadaProvaBean.concordoAcima}">  
               <p:ajax event="change" process = "concordoTermos avaliacao" update="btnEnviar" listener="#{segundaChamadaProvaBean.liberaBotaoEnviar()}"></p:ajax>
              </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>  
              <br/>  

              <p:commandButton id = "btnEnviar" disabled="#{!segundaChamadaProvaBean.concordoAcima}" value="Enviar" action="#{segundaChamadaProvaBean.testa()}" update="formulario"/>
              <br />
            <br />
            <b>GOIÂNIA, <h:outputLabel value = "#{segundaChamadaProvaBean.dataAtual}">
                         <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="medium"/>
                      </h:outputLabel></b>
            <br/>
            <h6>1. PREENCHER O REQUERIMENTO DE 2º CHAMADA, MEDIANTE O ORIGINAL DO ATESTADO MÊDICO ANEXO<br/>
            2. DEVOLVER O REQUERIMENTO AO PROTOCOLO GERAL, SOB PENA DE SER ENVALIDADO</h6>   
         </fieldset>
         </h:form>
         </ui:define>
      </ui:composition>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>Faculdade</display-name>
 <!--
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
-->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>


 <filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>
org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

if someone help pls..

Comment: Apparently, you're nesting forms.

Comment: The combination of Primefaces 4.x + Mojarra 2.2 fails submitting any input field in a multipart form. You should regress to Mojarra 2.1.x.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and its gone after I stopped submiting the form with ajax. You need to:

```
<p:commandButton id = "btnEnviar" disabled="#{!segundaChamadaProvaBean.concordoAcima}" value="Enviar" action="#{segundaChamadaProvaBean.testa()}" update="formulario" ajax="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```